How to use IDEVim to jump from an interface to its implementation class?
For example, in IDEA: Ctrl + Left-Click on the implementation to jump to it.
enter image description here
I asked the AI,and it give me this:
nnoremap <leader>gf :IdeActions gotoImplementation<CR>

I don't get any result when I type \gf in NORMAL mode.
it didn't solve my problem.

Which program are you using: Vim or IdeaVim? Please [edit] and remove the other tag. What are you trying to do? What steps did you take to accomplish your goal other than asking some AI? I voted to close as "needs details or clarity".
